# How to add additional augmentation to yolov8 model training

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-augmentation, yolov8, albumentations

I have tried to modify existig augument.py code in yolov8 repository but it is still implementing the default albumentations while training. Is there any method to add additonal albumentations.

This is what i have tried to add additonal albumentations.

```py
def __init__(self, p=1.0):
    """Initialize the transform object for YOLO bbox formatted params."""
    self.p = p
    self.transform = None
    prefix = colorstr('albumentations: ')
    try:
        import albumentations as A

        check_version(A.__version__, '1.0.3', hard=True)  # version requirement

        T = [
            A.Blur(p=0.01),
            A.MedianBlur(p=0.01),
            A.ToGray(p=0.01),
            A.CLAHE(p=0.01),
            A.RandomBrightnessContrast(p=0.5),
            A.RandomGamma(p=0.5),
            A.ImageCompression(quality_lower=75, p=0.5),
            A.MotionBlur(p=0.5, blur_limit=(3,9), always_apply=False)]  # transforms
        self.transform = A.Compose(T, bbox_params=A.BboxParams(format='yolo', label_fields=['class_labels']))

        LOGGER.info(prefix + ', '.join(f'{x}'.replace('always_apply=False, ', '') for x in T if x.p))
    except ImportError:  # package not installed, skip
        pass
    except Exception as e:
        LOGGER.info(f'{prefix}{e}')
```

But i don't see "ImageCompression" and "MotionBlur" albumentation in training process.

Comment: 75% JPEG quality isn't all that bad. how about you try _one_ transformation at a time, with p=1, and see how that looks

Comment: it would help if you didn't silently throw away the ImportException and maybe make sure you *see* whatever other exception could be thrown

Answer (score 0):

```
T = [
        A.Blur(p=0.01),
        A.MedianBlur(p=0.01),
        A.ToGray(p=0.01),
        A.CLAHE(p=0.01),
        A.RandomBrightnessContrast(p=0.5),
        A.RandomGamma(p=0.5),
        A.ImageCompression(quality_lower=75, p=0.5),
        A.MotionBlur(p=0.5, blur_limit=(3,9), always_apply=False)]  # transforms
]
```

Try changing the code above to the following.

```
T = [
         A.ImageCompression(quality_lower=75, p=0.5),
         A.MotionBlur(p=0.5, blur_limit=(3, 9), always_apply=False)
]
            
T += [
          A.Blur(p=0.01),
          A.MedianBlur(p=0.01),
          A.ToGray(p=0.01),
          A.CLAHE(p=0.01),
          A.RandomBrightnessContrast(p=0.5),
          A.RandomGamma(p=0.5)
]
```

Comment: that moves the ImageCompression and MotionBlur to *before* the other operations, rather than *after* them.

Comment: I have updated the existing code with the above changes but the model training logs show default argumentations only.
albumentations: Blur(p=0.01, blur_limit=(3, 7)), MedianBlur(p=0.01, blur_limit=(3, 7)), ToGray(p=0.01), CLAHE(p=0.01, clip_limit=(1, 4.0), tile_grid_size=(8, 8))

Comment: Inside your YOLOv8 training code, you would have a data loader responsible for loading images and applying augmentations. You'll need to modify this part to use your custom augmentations.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to the above problem.

step1:- Clone the yolov8 repository.

step2:- add change in augment.py file

step3:- run pip install e .

Step 4:- run the model training command given in the documentation of yolov8.